# Python recursive function - refer to current and previous arguments

Tags: python, recursion

I pass new arguments (previous_high, previous_score) to announce_highest, so how do I refer the the old arguments in order to do a comparison?

Sorry if this question is quite basic, still learning how recursive functions work!

---

```
def announce_highest(who, previous_high=0, previous_score=0):
    """Return a commentary function that announces when WHO's score
    increases by more than ever before in the game.

    >>> f0 = announce_highest(1) # Only announce Player 1 score gains
    >>> f1 = f0(11, 0)
    >>> f2 = f1(11, 1)
    1 point! That's the biggest gain yet for Player 1
    >>> f3 = f2(20, 1)
    >>> f4 = f3(5, 20) # Player 1 gets 4 points, then Swine Swap applies
    19 points! That's the biggest gain yet for Player 1
    >>> f5 = f4(20, 40) # Player 0 gets 35 points, then Swine Swap applies
    20 points! That's the biggest gain yet for Player 1
    >>> f6 = f5(20, 55) # Player 1 gets 15 points; not enough for a new high
    """
    assert who == 0 or who == 1, 'The who argument should indicate a player.'
    # BEGIN PROBLEM 7
    gain = #compare previous argument to current argument
    if gain > previous_high:
        if gain == 1:
            print(gain, 'point! That\'s the biggest gain yet for Player', who)
        else: 
            print(gain, 'points! That\'s the biggest gain yet for Player', who)

    return announce_highest(some args)
    # END PROBLEM 7
```

Comment: You'd have to manually pass them as well. Also, I can't see how this recursion would ever end. It seems like all paths lead back to `return announce_highest(who)`

Comment: It doesn't fill me with hope that you've even left "BEGIN PROBLEM 7" in the code. I suspect this is homework.

Comment: This does appear to be a homework question, (https://www.coursehero.com/file/p4uo74a4/A-strategy-is-a-function-that-takes-two-total-scores-as-arguments-the-current/). The exact code can be found online, so perhaps the asker is looking for an explanation rather than a code fix.

Answer (score 1):

[The problem from CS61A](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61a/fa17/proj/hog/#problem-7-2-pt) is described here.

Your first mistake is trying to make this a recursive function.  They are asking you to write a higher-order function (a higher-order function is a function that either takes a function as arguments or returns a function as part of its output; in our case we want one that returns a function).

Specifically, we want `announce_highest` to return a [*closure*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)).  A closure is basically a function (something that takes input, processes it, and returns output) that additionally has its own local environment of defined internal variables that it inherited from the environment where the closure was defined.

Your closure should have three internal variables:

- `who`, the player to announce when their score increases (either 0 or 1)
- `previous_high` the highest score that player you are tracking has ever had
- `previous_score` the score that the player you tracking last had

and this closure takes two parameters `current_player0_score` and `current_player1_score`.

Without doing your homework for you, here's two examples of a similar higher-order function that returns a closure.  First, I create a `my_counter_factory` closure creator.  It's a function that when called creates a counter which announces when the count is even or odd (depending on the value of the variables `announce_if_even_count` and `announce_if_odd_count` variables when it was initially created).

```
def my_counter_factory(initial_count=0, announce_if_even_count=True, announce_if_odd_count=False):
    count = initial_count
    def counter(increment_by):
        new_count = count + increment_by
        if announce_if_even_count and new_count % 2 == 0:
            print("Count is even %s" % new_count)
        if announce_if_odd_count and new_count % 2 == 1:
            print("Count is odd %s" % new_count)
        return my_counter_factory(new_count, announce_if_even_count, announce_if_odd_count)
    return counter
```

Which when run will work as:

```
 >>> c0 = my_counter_factory(10, True, True) # count = 10, announce count if even or odd

 >>> c1 = c0(5) # announces 15 creates new counter `c1` with count of 15 
                # note count of c0 is still 10.
 Count is odd 15

 >>> c2 = c1(3) # count is 18 (stored in new closure c2) by adding 3 to c1 count.  
 Count is even 18

 # See value of closures by incrementing 0 to them:
 >>> ignore = c0(0)
 Count is even 10
 >>> ignore = c1(0)
 Count is odd 15
 >>> ignore = c2(0)
 Count is even 18
```

Note every time this closure is called, it returns a brand new closure (with its own new environment).  An equally valid choice (that behaves slightly differently) is to not create new closures each time, but keep returning back the same closure.

```
def my_counter_factory(initial_count=0, announce_if_even_count=True, announce_if_odd_count=False):
    count = initial_count
    def counter(increment_by):
        nonlocal count  # more on this below.
        count += increment_by
        if announce_if_even_count and count % 2 == 0:
            print("Count is even %s" % count)
        if announce_if_odd_count and count % 2 == 1:
            print("Count is odd %s" % count)
        return counter # This returns back same closure each time.
    return counter
```

This will work as:

```
 >>> c0 = my_counter_factory(10, True, True) # count = 10, announce count if even or odd

 >>> c1 = c0(5) # adds 5 to count of c0 closure (was 10, now 15) announces 15 
 # c1 is a reference to the same closure as c0 with the same count                  
 Count is odd 15

 >>> c2 = c1(3) # adds 3 to count of c1 closure (now at 18), 
 Count is even 18

 # See value of closures by incrementing 0 to them:
 >>> ignore = c0(0)
 Count is even 18
 >>> ignore = c1(0)
 Count is even 18
 >>> ignore = c2(0)
 Count is even 18

 >>> c0 == c1 == c2  
 True
 # Note in this second example all three closures are identical, 
 # because the closure merely returns a reference to itself when called

 # Granted you could create a brand new closure
 >>> new_c = my_counter_factory(0, True, False) 
 # This one starts with a count of 0 and only announces when it's even
 >>> new_c2 = new_c(5)
```

Final Note: You may wonder why in the second example, we needed the line `nonlocal count` (but we didn't need it in the first example) and if you took it out you would get an error saying `local variable 'count' referenced before assignment`.  Closures in python are allowed to reference variables from the environment it was defined in (without using the `nonlocal` keyword introduced in python3), as long as they don't *re-assign* values to them.  Basically when python tries to interpret your function it differentiates between local variables (defined within the function) and variables defined elsewhere.  For example:

```
>>> def print_0_to_4():
...     for i in range(5):
...         print(i, end=", ")
...     print("")
... 
>>> i=-1
>>> print_0_to_4()
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
>>> i
-1
```

The important thing to note is we called a function `print_0_to_4` which assigned to a variable `i`, which made `i` a local variable.  Changes to the local variable in the function don't modify the values of variables with the same name from the outer environment.  (Otherwise programming would be ridiculously hard because we need to know the names of internal variables of every function we'd call for fear of unintentionally modifying our variables when calling a function).

Also note if you don't assign/modify to a variable in a function, then it is ok to reference a variable defined in another scope (without needing a `nonlocal` keyword).

```
>>> i = -1
>>> def print_i_from_outer_scope():
...     print(i)
... 
>>> print_i_from_outer_scope()
-1
```

Comment: Thank you - this is really helpful for my understanding